# Squarespace loading background image animation is not centering on desktop or mobile

Tags: html, css, animation, scale, squarespace

I've been building a simple website on Squarespace with a loading screen animation of a background image logo.

In the custom css I have:

```css
/* Loading screen cover page for Home */
.loading-screen {
  animation: screenFade .5s forwards 3.5s cubic-bezier(.25,.75,.5,1.25);
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

/* Loading screen logo */
.loading-screen-image {
  animation: animatedLogo 1.5s ease-in-out .5s alternate infinite none running;
  background-image: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/650180487d02863723c819ba/08fa27a0-cf09-413a-ae06-723b6703df35/Main+Logo_GOLD.png?content-type=image%2Fpng);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes animatedLogo {
  from {
    transform: scale(1); transform-origin: bottom center;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

When the animation starts, it moves and is off centered from the original position for some reason. I have a feeling it's something to do with the transform scale - even though I have tried playing around with the transform origin property to make the scaling come from the center of the image.

Another finding is that when I do not position the `.loading-screen-image`, the image is slightly off the screen - probably because of the `background-position` set. Perhaps this also affects the animations start position?

I tried this animation in codepen and it seems to work all fine.